# How to stop ServletRequestListener programmatically?

Tags: java, servlets

I am using ServletRequestListener  to execute certain logic when receiving requests from a web service java application. 
At some point, i want to stop listening to each request received. Is there a way to stop or disable the ServletRequestListener listener programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst it's possible to [add a listener programmatically](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addListener%28T%29), it is not possible to stop or remove a listener programmatically. Best what you can do is to let it check some application wide variable before continuing and then toggle that application wide variable instead.

E.g.

```
@Override
public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent event) {
    if (event.getServletContext().getAttribute("disableListener") == Boolean.TRUE) {
        return;
    }

    // Do the original job here.
}

@Override
public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent event) {
    if (event.getServletContext().getAttribute("disableListener") == Boolean.TRUE) {
        return;
    }

    // Do the original job here.
}
```

and to disable it, just do

```
servletContext.setAttribute("disableListener", true);
```

and to re-enable it, just do

```
servletContext.removeAttribute("disableListener");
```